# Local Backup of MySQL DB with Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have a MySQL database stored on AWS. I'm using Sequel Pro to manage it. I want to make a local copy for backup. In Sequel Pro, I see an option to File -> Export. I'm selecting SQL as the format. By default, the option to "Include Drop Table Syntax" is checked. Any ideas what this means? I want to rule out the possibility that it will drop my production AWS database after export.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means that the generated script will include `DROP TABLE` statements in addition to `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`. The statements will be executed when you run the script to restore the database.

Answer (score 2):

If checked it add a statement some thing like below before the CREATE TABLE statement

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_name;

The idea is you can import this exported sql in database with existing table